# "java.io.FileNotFoundException: No files matched spec" althought file is successfully written to

Tags: java, file, google-cloud-dataflow, filenotfoundexception, apache-beam

> Edit -- the error seems to come not from the *write* block but from
> the output block, which is even stranger. Modified to reflect my
> investigations.
>
> Edit2 -- solved - the issue is due to an improperly closed writer, for some reason only triggered in the DataflowRunner but not in the DirectRunner. Will add an answer later today when I find the time. If anyone has an insight on why the writer is closed in the DirectRunner but not in the DataflowRunner, I am very interested.

---

Consider the following Java 2.5.0 Dataflow code:

```
BlobId blobTranscriptId = BlobId.of(tempBucket, fileName);
BlobInfo blobTranscriptInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobTranscriptId).build();
try (WriteChannel writer = storageClient.writer(blobTranscriptInfo)) {
    LOG.info("Writing file");
    writer.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(currentString.toString().getBytes(UTF_8)));
    processContext.output("gs://" + tempBucket + "/" + fileName)
    LOG.info("Wrote " + fileName);
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOG.warn("Error caught while writing content : " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
}
```

When run locally (in a DirectPipeline), this code works fine and without errors.

When run in Dataflow (in a DataflowRunner) however, we notice a strange behavior:

- the file is created on the requested  bucket with the requested content and filename
- a `UserCodeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No files matched spec` is caught on the `processContext.output` line.

Searching on google *gcp "No files matched spec"* doesn't return a single result. Looking at the source in `org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.java` (error declared at line 173) is a not a lot more helpful.

Following the execution with a debugger shows that with a DirectRunner, the code *never calls* `FileIO.MatchAll`, the source of the error. With the DataflowRunner however, the error is somehow triggered. There is no reason why  the output string should be interpreted as a filepath since the stacktrace indicates that the error happens in this stage, which is declared as outputing a `PCollection<String>`.

**Why is a `FileNotFoundException` launched even though the file has clearly been created with the right content ?**

---

Some additional information that could help :

- the filename is generated through an UUID4 `UUID.randomUUID()`, which means that it contains '-' characters as well as long filenames. This should however not be an issue given that 1) it works in a DirectRunner 2) the files are actually created
- the following stage is a `TextIO.readAll()`
- stack trace (slightly modified for privacy): https://pastebin.com/wumha4ZZ

---

Additional investigation:

- Changing the output to a fixed string pointing an an exiting file `processContext.output("gs://" + tempBucket + "/" + alreadyExistingFileName);` does not trigger the error. I then suspected it might (somehow) be due to delay errors between the write operation and the time when the bucket acknowledges the file.
- Adding a `Thread.sleep(15000)` between the `write` and the `output` does NOT fix the issue. It seems that delay is not the issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking to the stacktrace in more details reveals that the errors happens through `FileIO`, itself called through the `TextIO` stage following this one.

What happens is that in my code above I do not close the writer `writer.close()` *before* outputing the string to `TextIO`, but *after* (through the `try(Writer writer){}` block). Since buckets do not register files until their writers have been closed, the TextIO can't find the files and launches a `FileNotFoundException`. This in turn closes the `try` block and launches `writer.close()`, which is why the file still appears on the bucket in the end.

For some reason I do not know, this does not happen when launching through a local `DirectLauncher`.